# Text Alignment Next to Icon on Bootstrap Sidebar

Tags: css, html, icons, bootstrap-4, sidebar

I'm trying to modify [dashboard](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/) from Bootstrap. I added icons before the texts on the sidebar similar to [this](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/). I did inspect the latter but it doesn't have something special CSS codes to make the texts have a uniform number of space and alignment.

This is my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">
            <div>
                <i id="icon-dashboard" class="fa fa-tachometer icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span class="nav-link-text">Dashboard</span> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/books">
            <div>
                <i id="icon-book" class="fa fa-book icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span class="nav-link-text">Book</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/transactions">
            <div>
                <i id="icon-transaction" class="fa fa-handshake-o icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span class="nav-link-text">Transaction</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/reports">                                
            <div></div>
            <div>
                <i id="icon-report" class="fa fa-bar-chart icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span class="nav-link-text">Report</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please help me figure out. I have no clue how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to the uneven spaces after the icon and before the text caused by icons of various widths?

Comment: Can you add a functional snippet

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The icons in question, in the example provided, apply a *fixed width* for a uniform layout throughout corresponding list-items; which may also have icons nested within them of varying widths.

Consider using **fixed width icons** by declaring the class `fa-fw` on icons in list-items.

> Use fa-fw to set icons at a fixed width. Great to use when different
>   icon widths throw off alignment. Especially useful in things like nav
>   lists & list groups.

[Font Awesome Examples - Fixed Width Icons](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#fixed-width)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.list-group {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Home</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Library</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Applications</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Settings</a>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad! I did not recognize the fa-fw used in the second link I provided. Thank you. I'll accept this as answer.

Comment: @JulezJupiter Easy thing to overlook - but now that you know, you'll probably never forget ;)

Comment: Yeah. With this, I think I'll be more diligent. Thanks, again.